# C++ to Java Code Conversion

Tags: java, c++

I have in C++

```
r.bits[k] &= 0xFF ^ msk;
```

So in Java

```
r.bits[k] = r.bits[k] & 0xFF,
```

but what is the meaning of the caret symbol? `msk` also will contain hexadecimal values. 
I know the caret symbol is a type of pointer in C++ but not sure what it is doing here.
Please explain.

Comment: This statement can be copied verbatim to Java. As silverback explains `^` has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ^ symbol represents the bitwise XOR operator in C, C++. [List of operators in C, C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++).

The same operator is available for Java as well. [XOR Operator in Java](http://java.comsci.us/etymology/operator/bitwise_xor.html).

Answer (score 5):

The caret means bitwise XOR

The caret does **NOT** mean a kind of pointer in C++ (though MSVC++ has extension for C++/CLI that use that symbol)

Answer (score 4):

Caret symbol in C++ means XOR logical operation. Meaning for the code `0xFF ^ msk;` is that you take bits in msk and invert them (zeroes to ones and vice versa)

Comment: I think you meant bitwise, not logical

Comment: it is a bitwise operator performing logical XOR operation

Answer (score 3):

The carat symbol is the xor operator see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

Answer (score 2):

The `^` is bitwise XOR.

For example:

```
1 ^ 1 = 0
2 ^ 1 = 3
0 ^ 1 = 1
```

If you are using C++/CLI then it is also a kind of [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx) (handle).